# Is there any storage uri that can be used to share an image without using write permissions in manifest?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-permissions

I want to share a screenahot from my app via SEND_ACTION intent. AFAIK it requires the file location to be available to all the apps but is there any other intent or uri path that can be accessed without write permissions in manifest like cache or something?
I dont want to up my permission count for this.
Thank you for any response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the file into a subdir of your apps cache-dir `getCacheDir()` and share it via a `content:` uri using the      [android.support.v4.content.FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Comment: Thank you gonna try it and follow up.

Comment: Thank you,it worked flawlessly right from the first attempt without even getting to another documentation except that you linked. It's a rare thing with me. Thank you very much. Sorry i cant vote up,still a newbie here